# Grouping of a well defined flat XML for Access import (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0

I have an output from our local accounting system, which consists of an envelope tag and just a repeated sequence of the fields, but not grouped. I have no prior experience in XSL but have been trying to find a solution for this and have found a solution, which works for XSLT 2.0. Unfortunately, it seems that Access 2007 only accepts XSLT 1.0 transformations.

Can you please help me find a XSLT 1.0 solution that works?

These are two records in the original flat XML:

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <DBCFIXED>  <DBCDATE>1-Apr-2011</DBCDATE>
    <DBCPARTY></DBCPARTY>
  </DBCFIXED>
  <DBCVCHTYPE>Stock Journal</DBCVCHTYPE>
  <DBCVCHNO>1</DBCVCHNO>
  <DBCVCHREF></DBCVCHREF>
  <DBCSTNO></DBCSTNO>
  <DBCSERVICETAXNO></DBCSERVICETAXNO>
  <DBCPANNO></DBCPANNO>
  <DBCCSTNO></DBCCSTNO>
  <DBCNARR>Opening balance transfar</DBCNARR>
  <DBCQTY>0.000 Kg</DBCQTY>
  <DBCRATE></DBCRATE>
  <DBCAMOUNT></DBCAMOUNT>
  <DBCADDLCOST></DBCADDLCOST>
  <DBCGROSSAMT></DBCGROSSAMT>
  <DBCLEDAMT></DBCLEDAMT>
  <DBCFIXED>  <DBCDATE></DBCDATE>
    <DBCPARTY>ME KN YARN BL 1</DBCPARTY>
  </DBCFIXED>
  <DBCVCHTYPE></DBCVCHTYPE>
  <DBCVCHNO></DBCVCHNO>
  <DBCVCHREF></DBCVCHREF>
  <DBCSTNO></DBCSTNO>
  <DBCSERVICETAXNO></DBCSERVICETAXNO>
  <DBCPANNO></DBCPANNO>
  <DBCCSTNO></DBCCSTNO>
  <DBCNARR></DBCNARR>
  <DBCQTY>0.150 Kg</DBCQTY>
  <DBCRATE>566.00/Kg</DBCRATE>
  <DBCAMOUNT>-84.90</DBCAMOUNT>
  <DBCADDLCOST></DBCADDLCOST>
  <DBCGROSSAMT></DBCGROSSAMT>
  <DBCLEDAMT></DBCLEDAMT>
</ENVELOPE>
```

For the import into Access, I need the data to be grouped into records starting with DBCFIXED until the next DBCFIXED. Something like:

```
<InventoryDaybook>
  <record>
    <DBCFIXED>  
      <DBCDATE>1-Apr-2011</DBCDATE>
      <DBCPARTY/>
    </DBCFIXED>
    <DBCVCHTYPE>Stock Journal</DBCVCHTYPE>
    <...></...>
  </record>
  <record>
    <...></...>
  </record>
/<InventoryDaybook>
```

The XSLT 2.0 code that works is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <InventoryDaybook>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="DBCFIXED">
      <record>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </record>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </InventoryDaybook>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is amazing what can be done with XSL but my knowledge seems just too little.. Thanks in advance for your help and your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved in XSLT1.0 by means of a **xsl:key**, that matches non-DBCFIXED elements, and uses the first preceding DBCFIXED element as the key

```
<xsl:key 
    name="records" 
    match="ENVELOPE/*[not(self::DBCFIXED)]" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::DBCFIXED[1])" />
```

Then, when you match the individual **DBCFIXED** elements, you can easily look-up the associated elements that make up the record

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('records', generate-id())" />
```

Here is the full XLST

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="records" match="ENVELOPE/*[not(self::DBCFIXED)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::DBCFIXED[1])" />
   <xsl:template match="/ENVELOPE">
      <InventoryDaybook>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="DBCFIXED" />
      </InventoryDaybook>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DBCFIXED">
      <record>
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('records', generate-id())" />
      </record>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input XML, the following is output

```
<InventoryDaybook>
   <record>
      <DBCFIXED>
         <DBCDATE>1-Apr-2011</DBCDATE>
         <DBCPARTY/>
      </DBCFIXED>
      <DBCVCHTYPE>Stock Journal</DBCVCHTYPE>
      <DBCVCHNO>1</DBCVCHNO>
      <DBCVCHREF/>
      <DBCSTNO/>
      <DBCSERVICETAXNO/>
      <DBCPANNO/>
      <DBCCSTNO/>
      <DBCNARR>Opening balance transfar</DBCNARR>
      <DBCQTY>0.000 Kg</DBCQTY>
      <DBCRATE/>
      <DBCAMOUNT/>
      <DBCADDLCOST/>
      <DBCGROSSAMT/>
      <DBCLEDAMT/>
   </record>
   <record>
      <DBCFIXED>
         <DBCDATE/>
         <DBCPARTY>ME KN YARN BL 1</DBCPARTY>
      </DBCFIXED>
      <DBCVCHTYPE/>
      <DBCVCHNO/>
      <DBCVCHREF/>
      <DBCSTNO/>
      <DBCSERVICETAXNO/>
      <DBCPANNO/>
      <DBCCSTNO/>
      <DBCNARR/>
      <DBCQTY>0.150 Kg</DBCQTY>
      <DBCRATE>566.00/Kg</DBCRATE>
      <DBCAMOUNT>-84.90</DBCAMOUNT>
      <DBCADDLCOST/>
      <DBCGROSSAMT/>
      <DBCLEDAMT/>
   </record>
</InventoryDaybook>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Tim, that works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to Tim for first correct solution. Whilst Tim's is absolutely correct, I just want to bring to the OP's attention, that there are two general forms of solution to XSLT 1.0 group-starting-with - One where the head node is excluded from the key (as in Tim's case), and the other where the head node is included (shown below). I am not sure which is superior. Perhaps Dimitre can tell us.

So for interest sake, here is the alternate form, which includes the head node in the key.

### Head-node-included-in-key form

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="records" match="ENVELOPE/*" use="generate-id(
            (preceding-sibling::DBCFIXED|self::DBCFIXED)[last()])" />

   <xsl:template match="/ENVELOPE">
      <InventoryDaybook>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="DBCFIXED" mode="group-head" />
      </InventoryDaybook>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DBCFIXED" mode="group-head">
      <record>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('records', generate-id())" />
      </record>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Very slight advantages

1. key match condition simpler.
2. One less line in the template for the head node.
3. The head node goes through apply-templates rather than directly copy-of. This may be of benefit if you are doing more than just straight copy.

### Very slight disadvantages

1. Key use attribute more complicated
2. Have to add modes to discriminate between grouping the head node and down-stream processing of it. Although in way, this is also an advantage, as the mode designators improve self-documentation.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for the alternative solution. Really appreciate the additional approaches! For some reason it creates an overflow error due to infinite recursion in Access, though. Same on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ where it gives back a looping warning.

Comment: Thanks again Sean. Very interesting to see both ways of doing this. I definitively need to have a look at how the modes work with apply-templates. And I think this might be also very interesting to compare for other posters with a similar question.